# How can I execute this shell command in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I can execute the following command against a Git submodule on my terminal. I basically just want to print out the path of the child module.

My Git submodule looks like

```
/path/submodule/module1
               /module2
```

I can do this on the command line to print out the name of each child module

```
$ git submodule foreach 'echo $name'
Entering 'module1'
module1
Entering 'module2'
module2
```

However, if I do the following

```
node("buildNode)" {
  stage("test") {
    sh(label: "Test",
       returnStatus: true,
       script: """
         git submodule foreach 'echo $name'
       """)
  }
}
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: WorkflowScript
```

What's the correct syntax? TIA

Comment: I think this is scripted syntax which does not use `steps{}`? Otherwise that does seem like the answer.

Comment: this is a scripted pipeline, not declarative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is...

```
node("buildNode)" {
  stage("test") {
    sh(label: "Test",
       returnStatus: true,
       script: """
         git submodule foreach 'echo \$name'
       """)
  }
}
```

Notice the `\$name`.